# Product Name started by a number gets replaced in Xcode by "_"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, product

Xcode 4.0.2 is driving me crazy with this new error.

I have an App with a Product Name that is started with a number, let's say "3Dgame". The problem is Xcode transform "3Dgame" to "_Dgame" so my App ID com.myenterprise._Dgame obviously doesn't match with the App ID of the Provisionning Profile.

Anyone with a hint of how to avoid this annoying behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: Same thing. I am able to download it and install but, after it is done, app's icon does not show up anywhere. Will try renaming it.

Comment: that did it for me. You may try editing .plist file of your distribution package and changing _Dgame back, but I doubt it will work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the app ID in the plist directly. In general it is not a good idea to start a project title with a digit, since variables in most programming languages cannot start with digits, and the name of your Xcode project might get translated into variable names in various places; so Xcode simply removes a starting digit to avoid bad behavior. So you can still name your project with a digit, you just can't expect that behind the scenes it will always remain that way.

It's not much of an issue since the App ID you are needing is easily changed to anything you want.